# Android Palette

Tags: java, android, color, android-palette

От сервера приходит картинка, на которую накладывается TextView. 
Вот если картинка белая TextView должен быть черным, и наоборот. Вопрос как динамически определить общий цвет картинки. Поможет ли библиотека Palette?

Comment: Общий цвет может быть не только белый или чёрный. Обычно для `TextView` делается прозрачный на ~80% бекграунд (белый или чёрный) и это нормально выглядит на любой картинке

Comment: Да, с palette можно определить доминирующий цвет, делал как-то такое